VSCode launch.json file been replaced
in VSCode I have a launch.json file in my project that has 2 configurations that run at the same time one for the apoi and the other one for the front end. It that was working fine until yesterday. I don't know what I changed that now when I run my app in dev the configuration name for the front end name remains the same but the api gets changed to ".NET Core Launch (web)" before yesterday both names remain the same. And, I am not just concerned about the name but where does it gets ".NET Core Launch (web)" from and how to make it go back to my configuration. (See image)

